# Why was IEquatable T not made contravariant in T for C# 4.0?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

IEquatable<T> could have been declared to be contravariant in T, since it only uses T in an input position (or, equivalently, U being a subtype of T should imply that IEquatable<T> is [a subtype of] IEquatable<U>).

So, why did the BCL team not annotate it (for C# 4.0) with the 'in' keyword, as they did with many other generic interfaces (like the entirely analogous IComparable)?

Comment: The problems mentioned in the thread [Should `IEquatable<T>`, `IComparable<T>` be implemented on non-`sealed` classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868316/should-iequatablet-icomparablet-be-implemented-on-non-sealed-classes) would just become much worse if `IEquatable<>` was contravariant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think this is mainly for a philosophical reason rather than a technical limitation–as it's perfectly possible to simply annotate the interface. `IEquatable<T>` is meant to compare objects of the same type for exact equality. An instance of a superclass is not usually considered equal to an instance of a subclass. Equality in this sense implies type equality too. This is a bit different from `IComparable<in T>`. It can be sensible to define a relative sort order across different types.

To quote [MSDN page on `IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx):

> Notes to Implementers:
>
> Replace the type parameter of the `IEquatable<T>` interface with **the type that is implementing this interface**.

This sentence further demonstrates the fact that `IEquatable<T>` is meant to work between instances of a single concrete type.

Comment: Thanks; I suspect this is close to the truth. It seems a shame, though, as U being a subtype of T really does mean that IEquatable T is equatable to U... it's just not IEquatable to U! In other words, I don't see any downside to annotating the interface...

Comment: I honestly don't see any *upside* to making it contravariant. It wouldn't make sense to say that an instance of, say, `Vehicle` is exactly equal to -- effectively identical to -- an instance of `Car`. They could be equivalent for sort order (as with IComparable), but they would never be really "equal".

Comment: @Khalid: Considering that an ideal base type should not be aware of details of its derived types, it's not in a position to decide equality of those types. A derived class may add some properties, thus diverging from the equality definition that base class provides.

Comment: Your valid point about implementation applies even without variance, since one can always pass a subtype to the Equals method at runtime anyway, just because of polymorphism. As things are (without the contravariant annotation) the compiler does not let you express the runtime fact that IEquatable<T> unavoidably acts like IEquatable<U> whenever U is a subtype of T (because of polymorphism, input-only parameters are unavoidably logically contravariant). This inconsistency has arisen because it's up to the BCL team to manually declare the truth about variance on a case-by-case basis...

Answer (score 2):

Inheritable types should generally not implement `IEquatable<T>`.  If `IEquatable<T>` included a `GetHashCode()` method, one could define the semantics of `IEquatable<T>` to say that items should compare equal when examined as T's.  Unfortunately, the fact that `IEquatable<T>` is bound to the same hash code as `Object.Equals` means that in general `IEquatable<T>` has to implement essentially the same semantics as `Object.Equals`.

Consequently, if an implementation of `IEquatable<BaseClass>` does anything other than call `Object.Equals` within it, a derived class which overrides `Object.Equals` and `GetHashCode()` and does not re-implement `IEquatable<BaseClass>` will end up with a broken implementation of that interface; an implementation of `IEquatable<BaseClass>` which simply calls `Object.Equals` will work just fine, even in that scenario, but will offer no real advantage over a class which doesn't implement `IEquatable<T>`.

Given that inheritable classes shouldn't be implementing `IEquatable<T>` in the first place, the notion of covariance is not relevant to proper implementations of the interface.