# Why doesn't List.Contains work with my code?

Tags: c#, list, contains

I'm using List.Contains to tell whether a variable is inside the list or not, but it keeps on returning that it isn't when it is.

I've looked up [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx) and I've noticed that I have to inherit from IEquatable and implement my own .Equals method. The actual class is inheriting from another one, so I've written the .Equals method **in the base class**.

Here's the code of the class "Actividad":

```
abstract public class Actividad:IEquatable<Actividad> {

    protected int codigo;

    [...]

    public bool  Equals(Actividad otra)
    {
        return this.Codigo == otra.Codigo;
    }   
}
```

and here's the definition of the child class "Actividad_a":

```
public class Actividad_a : Actividad{ [...] }
```

This is the code that checks whether something is inside the list:

```
private void loadDisponibles() {

    foreach (Actividad_a act in Program.Asignaturas) {

        if (!user1.ActAcademicas.Contains(act)) {
           doSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

`Program.Asignaturas` and `user1.ActAcademicas` are both defined as `List<Actividad_a>`.

The problem is that `!user1.ActAcademicas.Contains(act)` always returns true, no matter the data is in the list or not.

My first guess is that I have to inherit from IEquatable and implement .Equals method in each derived class, but I'm not really sure about it.

Comment: Is the list empty when you check contains?

Comment: As far as I've checked, it has one element. Although I don't check whether it has anything. Does it matter?

Comment: `Contains` uses `Equals` so yes, you must implement it.

Comment: Maybe set a breakpoint in the `Equals` method to verify `List<>` is indeed calling it.

Comment: Are you setting `codigo` anywhere?  Also, the equals method you've posted uses `Codigo`, which is not the same as `codigo`.

Comment: I think the problem here is you have to override `Object.Equals`, not make a new one.

Comment: @phoog yes, `codigo` is set. And `Codigo` is actually just a get. Sorry for not including it.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I've set the breakpoint, and it isn't called. But if I write it as `public override bool  Equals(Actividad otra)` it says it has no suitable member to invalidate

Comment: @Fawques - You need to override `Equals(object)` instead..

Comment: Fawques: ok, I was just checking to be sure :)  @MikeChristensen is suggesting to override `public override bool Equals(object otra)`, as Vadim also suggests in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're comparing Actividad_a and the Contains method is expecting it to implement `IEquatable<Actividad_a>` rather than `IEquatable<Actividad>`

Try overriding the default Equals method as well

```
public override bool Equals(object otra)
{
    var actividad = otra as Actividad;
    if (actividad == null) return false;
    return this.Codigo == actividad.Codigo;
}
```

EDIT:

Some more info: .NET 4.0 introduced flexibility for working with generics called Contravariance and Covariance http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx

> Covariant and contravariant generic type parameters provide greater
>   flexibility in assigning and using generic types. For example,
>   covariant type parameters enable you to make assignments that look
>   much like ordinary polymorphism. Suppose you have a base class and a
>   derived class, named Base and Derived. Polymorphism enables you to
>   assign an instance of Derived to a variable of type Base. Similarly,
>   because the type parameter of the IEnumerable(Of T) interface is
>   covariant, you can assign an instance of IEnumerable
>   (IEnumerable(Of Derived) in Visual Basic) to a variable of type
>   IEnumerable
>
> In general, a covariant type parameter can be used as the return type
>   of a delegate, and contravariant type parameters can be used as
>   parameter types. For an interface, covariant type parameters can be
>   used as the return types of the interface's methods, and contravariant
>   type parameters can be used as the parameter types of the interface's
>   methods.

For some reason `IEquatable<T>` [was not made contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289440/why-was-iequatable-t-not-made-contravariant-in-t-for-c-sharp-4-0) and why your original approach won't work

Comment: Or, as OP suspects, he could implement IEquatable<DerivedType> on every type derived from Actividad.  Overriding `object.Equals` in `Actividad` is the better approach, however, so +1.  (Also, you need the override keyword in your example code.)

Comment: This worked smoothly :). I also had to inherit from IEquatable<object>

Comment: @Fawques, you shouldn't actually have to inherit from IEquatable<object> as all objects have an Equals method as it is.

Comment: I just did a override on Equals for my object and it worked like a charm.  Thanks!