# MSDN code example: why does it cast before calling base.Equals(object)?

Tags: c#, equals, equality

In Microsoft's MSDN Library article on `Object.Equals` Method (Object), (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx) an example is presented to demonstrate how to override Equals. It looks like this:

```
class Point
{
   ... // IEquatable<Point> is not implemented.

   public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
   {
      //Check for null and compare run-time types. 
      if ((obj == null) || ! this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType())) {
         return false;
      }
      else { 
         Point p = (Point) obj; 
         return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
      }   
   }
}

sealed class Point3D: Point 
{
   int z;

   public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
   {
      Point3D pt3 = obj as Point3D;
      if (pt3 == null)
         return false;
      else 
         return base.Equals((Point)obj) && z == pt3.z; // Here!!!
   }
}
```

In the ensuing documentation, my attention was drawn to the following statement.

(If it is a `Point3D` object, it is **cast** to a `Point` object and passed to the base class implementation of `Equals`.)

Here, `return base.Equals((Point)obj)` why bother casting obj into `Point`?

#### Update:

I guess it might just be a typo, as I check the .NET 4.0 version document, it is a one-liner:

```
return base.Equals(obj) && z == ((Point3D)obj).z
```

Comment: Doesn't look like good code to me. The cast means that they get an `InvalidCastException` if `obj` is of an exotic type. Not nice. __Edit:__ Nah, sorry, too fast. They know the type is `Point3D`, so no exception, just silly-looking code.

Comment: Maybe it should be passing in `pt3`, which has already been casted, not `obj`. EDIT: or at least just passing in `obj` and let the base implementation handle casting/type checking.

Comment: I *think* they're trying to make the base class method work despite the `!this.GetType().Equals()` check. (Trying pointlessly. The right way would probably be using `IEquatable<T>` instead of overriding `Object.Equals()` for comparisons in class hierarchies.)

Comment: Or, obviously, avoiding crazy hierarchies of data structures. `Point3D` extending from `Point` to save two field definitions seems like bad use of inheritance.

Comment: @millimoose However, when comparing two `Point3D` it will still work. In the base class, both `GetType()` and `obj.GetType()` will return `typeof(Point3D)`, so all is good. But it's ugly code.

Comment: Maybe they're just trying to make it more explicit that the `base.Equals((Point)obj)` will be check the `Point` fields as though it's a `Point`, _then_ if that passes also check the `Point3D.z` field. Maybe they ("they" as in MSDN authors) _think_ this makes the information/lesson in the MSDN article more articulate or somehow more teachable for implementing `Object.Equals`.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Maybe, but it's not optimal, and I suspect the "silly" cast will generate some extra IL for no reason.

Comment: I fully agree. This is _not_ the best way to implement `Equals`; just speculating _why_ the MSDN article was written  the way it is.

Comment: @millimoose It is not recommended to implement `IEquatable<T>` on non-sealed type http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868316/should-iequatablet-icomparablet-be-implemented-on-non-sealed-classes

Comment: @colinfang Interesting thread! I don't agree with its conclusion, though. Just wrote a couple of comments in it. The way I see it, all that thread proves is that when you implement `Equals` you **must** check to see if `GetType() != other.GetType()`. If so, return `false`.

Comment: If the passed-in object is anything other than a `Point3d` or derivative thereof, the expression `obj as Point3d` will be null.  If `Point3d` inherits from `Point`, then any cast from `Point3d` to `Point` will succeed.  The cast doesn't seem dangerous, but it also doesn't really do anything.  I think the purpose of the cast may be to allow for the possibility that the base class might have an overload which expects an argument of type `Point`, but such things can be dangerous with types that participate in widening conversions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* no point (haha) to casting `obj` to a `Point`. You are right that the `Point.Equals` method will also cast it to a `Point`. It is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

When one requires equality-checking, the recommendation today is to implement the [`IEquatable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) generic interface. Its [`Equals(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190.aspx) method provides type-safety and avoids boxing/unboxing overheads for value types.

If the `Point` class implemented the `IEquatable<Point>` interface, it would contain an `Equals(Point)` method overload, which is more efficient to call than `Equals(Object)`. A plausible justification could be that the type-cast to `Point` is done pre-emptively in case the said interface gets implemented.

```
class Point : IEquatable<Point>
{
   public Equals(Point other)
   {
       return other != null && this.x == other.x && this.y == other.y;
   }

   public override bool Equals(Object obj) 
   {
       return this.Equals(obj as Point);
   }
}
```

Comment: You should still check if `GetType() == other.GetType()` in the type-safe overload (the interface implementation) when your `class` is not `sealed`!

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: That's debatable. If the base-class fields of a derived-class instance are equal to the current base-class instance, then the two might still be considered equal.

Comment: 1. `Point` is not value type. 2. It is not recommended to implement `IEquatable<T>` on non-sealed class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868316/should-iequatablet-icomparablet-be-implemented-on-non-sealed-classes

Comment: Maybe debatable. But you jeopardize the symmetry of the `Equals` "relation". That is, if I derive from your type (you didn't seal it) and introduce the new `z` component, then `jeppes3DPointInstance.Equals(douglasPointInstance)` would surely return `false`. But I can't get your type to behave "correctly" with `douglasPointInstance.Equals(jeppes3DPointInstance)`.

Comment: Inheritable types should generally not implement `IEquatable<T>`, since there's no good pattern for assuring that invoking `IEquatable<BaseType>.Equals(BaseType)` on a derived-type object will yield behavior consistent with its override of `Object.Equals(Object)`, except by having the former method chain to the latter (which would negate all of the performance benefits of implementing the interface in the first place).

Comment: @supercat: I feel that a good pattern should be possible to support hierarchical equality through polymorphism (like there exists the [Dispose Patten](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e.aspx)), but I can't seem to come across one at the moment. I might come back to this post in the future.

Comment: @Douglas: There is a pattern: `Object.Equals`.  There are at least two kinds of equivalence relations which are well-defined for all possible pairs of class objects; since the result of comparing any *class* object to any other is well-defined (an apple shouldn't refuse to compare itself to an orange--it should simply report that it's not equivalent), it makes sense for `Equals` to take a parameter of type `Object`).  If a type `T` is not inheritable, there's no need to check the type of an object passed as a `T` parameter, but if it is inheritable, type checking is necessary.

Comment: @supercat: My argument is that, for inheritable types, the equality between a base-class instance and a derived-class class is domain-dependent. If a derived class does not alter the identity of the base class – say, it simply provides a layer of memoization over the base class's computed properties – then it shouldn't be constrained to be non-equal just because it's a different type.

Comment: @Douglas: Checking whether a class object passed as a `T` is in fact an instance of `T` (as opposed to a derivative type) is no cheaper than testing whether an object passed as `Object` is an instance of `T`, so constraining a parameter to be of type `T` doesn't really buy anything.  If `IEquatable<T>` included its own `GetHashCode` method, it might be helpful to have it implement a different sort of equivalence from `Object.Equals()` [IMHO, that would be less bad than having types like `Decimal` override `Object.Equals` to mean something other than strict equivalence] but it doesn't.

Comment: @Douglas: There is nothing wrong with having an `IEqualityComparer<T>` which can regard things of different types as equivalent, but I think `Object.Equals` should represent a fairly strict form of equality which would generally preclude that.  I know what you're getting at, and have a pattern for it; I can discuss more in chat if you like.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33207/discussion-between-douglas-and-supercat)

Answer (score 0):

In the Point class we are comparing the types:

```
this.GetType().Equals(obj.GetType())
```

The Type Point is not equal to Point3D.

Comment: Seems to me that the Equals function on the base class is no well defined

Comment: The cast `(Point)obj` doesn't change the identity of the object being referred. It's just a (useless in this case) reference conversion. The `GetType()` will always return the true runtime type, no matter what compile-time type. Checking if `GetType()` and `obj.GetType()` are the same is a very good thing to do when overriding `Equals` for a non-sealed class type.