# Does a class that inherits another class inherit that classes inherited classes/interfaces?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have two classes :

```
public class Question : IDisposable, IEquatable<Question>
{
}

public class SessionQuestion : Question, IDisposable, IEquatable<SessionQuestion>
{
}
```

As `Question` inherits `IDisposable` and `IEquatable`, does `SessionQuestion` implicitly inherit those interfaces as well?

Comment: Yup. Try yourself, do `SessionQuestion s = new SessionQuestion();` then `if (s is IDisposable)`

Comment: Attention: Not that you get confused. Due to inheritance, *SessionQuestion* inherits `IEquatable<Question>` from *Question*. However, *SessionQuestion* also implements `IEquatable<SessionQuestion>`, which is a different interface than `IEquatable<Question>`. Thus, you could omit specifying the *IDisposable* interface for *SessionQuestion* (it is inherited from *Question*), but you would need to keep `IEquatable<SessionQuestion>` (as this interface is not implemented by *Question*)

Comment: @elgonzo excellent point!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029791/how-can-i-properly-override-a-class-method-property-in-a-derived-class as a follow up question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Will, i just extended my answer to illustrate some weird and entertaining gotchas than can happen when a class inherits an interface from its base class while at the same time providing some explicit implementations of members of that interface. Enjoy :-D

Comment: @elgonzo is right. But note that implementing `IEquatable<>` on a `class` that is not `sealed` may be a bad idea. See [Should IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T> be implemented on non-sealed classes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1868316/) for more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is "Yes" -- interfaces are inherited. However, whether you can omit including interface definitions from a class depends on whether that class wants to have certain interface members as [explicit interface implementations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx).

Let's take this very simple (and silly) example:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    void foo();
}

public class A : IMyInterface
{
    public void foo()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("A.foo() executed");
    }
}

public class B : A, IMyInterface
{
    void IMyInterface.foo()
    {
        Console.Out.WriteLine("B.foo() executed");
    }
}
```

Since B wants to have the *foo()* method as an [explicit interface implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461.aspx), the *IMyInterface* interface has to be specified as part of its class definition -- even if class A already implements this interface. Inheriting an interface declaration from a base class is not sufficient in this case.

If class B would not have explicit interface implementations, then class B does not need to specify the interface (*IMyInterface* in this little example) again.

Inheriting an interface from a base class and having some explicit interface implementation for members of that interface can lead to effects which can be surprising at best, and at worst can lead to broken/buggy software.

If you execute the following code sequence:

```
A obj = new A();
obj.foo();
IMyInterface x = obj;
x.foo();
```

the output will be

> A.foo() executed
>   A.foo() executed

However, let's now use an object of type B but otherwise keep the code exactly the same:

```
B obj = new B();
obj.foo();
IMyInterface x = obj;
x.foo();
```

the output will be somewhat different:

> A.foo() executed
>   B.foo() executed

Why is that so? Remember that class B inherits the implementation of the *foo()* method from class A. Thus, calling `obj.foo()` will still execute the inherited *foo()* method.

Now, why is then `x.foo()` not invoking the *foo()* implementation provided by class A as well? Or, why is `obj.foo()` not invoking the implementation given for *foo()* in class B?

Because *x* is a variable of type **IMyInterface**, thus the explicit interface implementation of the *foo()* method provided by the object of type B takes precedence when invoking `x.foo()`. The variable *obj* is **not** of type *IMyInterface*, hence `obj.foo()` will not invoke the explicit interface implementation of the *foo()* method.

Because of these surprising results it is easy to understand why explicit interface implementations for interfaces which are already implemented by a base class is really a bad idea in most cases. As the saying goes: **Just because you can does not mean you should**.

Comment: The technical term here is [Interface re-implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664594.aspx). A less confusing alternative to it may be to implement an interface in a base class by a `public` ***`virtual`*** method/property/etc.

Answer (score 3):

Of course.

In fact, the .NET Framework is not at all a flat class hierachy. Pick a random class and take a look. You'll see that it derives a class that derives a class that..., and so on.

Interfaces are also inherited to grand children, just like normal classes are.

And as for members you have to implement: If you implemented them in `Question`, you don't need to implement them in `SessionQuestion`, of course.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you'll still need to implement all the members that the interfaces define. However, if the base class contains a member that matches an interface member, the base class member can work as the implementation of the interface member and you are not required to manually implement it again.