# How can I properly override a class method/property in a derived class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

Follow up from [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029512/does-a-class-that-inherits-another-class-inherit-that-classes-inherited-classes) Question -

In the `Question` class I have the following properties (I'm simplifying here)

```
public class Question : IDisposable, IEquatable<Question>{
    protected virtual DataRow Row{ get { return DataTable.Rows[0]; } }
    public string Value { get { return this.Row.Field<string>("Value"); } }
}
```

now, for the `SessionQuestion` class I want to keep this in play, but I want to read the Value field from a *different* data table :

```
public class SessionQuestion : Question, IEquatable<SessionQuestion>{
    protected override DataRow Row { get { return OtherDataTable.Rows[0]; } }
}
```

Now, if I were to say something like :

```
new SessionQuestion( ).Value
```

would that return the value from `DataTable.Rows[0]`, or `OtherDataTable.Rows[0]`? I want it to return the value from `OtherDataTable`, so if this doesn't work, what would I need to do so it would work properly?

Comment: Didn't you mean *SessionQuestion* inheriting from *Question*? In your code in the question *SessionQuestion*  does not inherit *Question*... ;)

Comment: fffffff...ixed thanks.

Comment: Why don't you try it out and see....

Comment: It would return `OtherDataTable.Rows[0]`, because *SessionQuestion*'s *Row* property **override**s the implementation of the *Row* property in *Question* ;)

Comment: Serious point though, in both this question and your previous one, you could have figured it out by running both examples.

Comment: @DavidG This wasn't some sort of rep grab; while these would be simple enough to write a 15 minute application, then what? I could still post the question and answer it myself, or I could ask the question and many people could benefit.

Comment: Surely if it takes you longer to write the questions than work out the answers for yourself, then those questions don't need to be asked on SO?